# Convert pptx file to binary to store in db and then convert back to pptx after retrieval

Tags: r, postgresql, serialization, binary

I saw this post:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/storing-and-retrieving-files-images-in-a-database-from-shiny-app/28122

And wanted to find out how to convert a binary back to the normal file type before it was converted to binary. In the post it mentions these steps:

- retrieve bytes (as hex) from database if / when necessary...
- serialize to a file for presentation if / when necessary

How do I serialize back to a file, in this case a pptx file that was stored in a sql db that a shinyR app will interface with. Appreciate your time and guidance. Thanks.

```
# open pptx as binary and write as binary to new location
rtn_filename <- "/path/to/pptx-file"
read_ppt <- readBin(rtn_filename, what= raw(), n=file.info(rtn_filename)$size)
con = file(file.path(dirname(rtn_filename), "ppt_binary.dat"), "wb")
writeBin(object = read_ppt, con = con)
close(con)

# read the binary file
filepath <- file.path(dirname(rtn_filename), "ppt_binary.dat")
binary_file <- readBin(filepath, what = raw(), n=file.info(filepath))

    
sql_smt <- "UPDATE PPTFILES SET PPT_FILE = $1 where experiment_id = 'FY21w1p214';" 

# upload to sql db
rs  <- dbExecute(
  con, 
  statement=sql_smt, 
  list(paste0("\\x", paste(binary_file, collapse = "")))
)

# check that the original file and what is in the db is the same
get_res <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT PPT_FILE from PPTFILES WHERE experiment_id = 'FY21w1p214'")
identical(get_res$ppt_file[[1]], binary_file) #TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done file uploading/downloading on a Postgresql database.

In this database the option I used for the field type is TEXT.

if your are using SQL Server maybe nvarchar(max) is the best fit for this method.

The idea behind this method is to encode the file in base64 and insert this as text in the database. Because of encoding the data size will be bigger than original file. It doesn't matter what kind of file contents or format you have, powerpoint or another. You are best if doing encoding directly in R.

The following code will work if executed in postgresql. Do the adjustments if using another dbms, or maybe it can work unchanged I haven't checked since I don't have an SQL server at hand:

In database

```
CREATE TABLE files_table
(
    file_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    file_content TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

In R, to save a file to DB

```
library(base64enc)
library(DBI)
pg = dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
file_name <- "/tmp/some_file.pptx"
file_content <- base64encode(file_name)
con = dbConnect(pg, user="user", password="password",
              host="hostname", port=5432, dbname="dbname")
qry <- sprintf("INSERT INTO files_table ( file_name, file_content ) values( '%s', '%s')",file_name, file_content)
dbExecute(con,qry)
```

To load a file by filename from DB and write it to disk by the same name as it was loaded

```
## same code from before to connect to database here and same libraries
file_name <- "/tmp/some_file.pptx"
qry <- sprintf("SELECT file_content FROM files_table WHERE file_name='%s' LIMIT 1",file_name)
data <- dbGetQuery(con, qry)
raw_data <- base64decode(data[1,]$file_content)
write.filename = file(file_name, "wb")
writeBin(raw_data,write.filename)
close(write.filename)
```

It won't handle well duplicated file names of course, depending on use case it could be important or not.

Comment: thank you. good idea to use base64 encoding!